# Let D be the midpoint of side BC of $\triangle ABC$. Prove that if AD>BD $\angle A$ is acute.

Tags: geometry

The problem doesn't specify if $\angle A=\angle BAD$ or $\angle A=\angle BAC$. If it is the former part, I know how to solve the problem.
Can anyone please clarify whether it's the former or latter part. If it is the latter part, can someone give me a solution too?

Comment: What is the midpoint of a triangle?  The centroid?

Answer (score 1):

It should be the latter.

By Apollonius Theorem we have,

$c^2+b^2=2(BD^2+AD^2)$

Given $a^2=4BD^2<2(AD^2+BD^2)$

So, $c^2+b^2-a^2>0$

So, $\cos A=\frac{c^2+b^2-a^2}{2bc}>0$

So, $ \angle A$ is acute

Answer (score 0):

[image]

We are given $BD=CD<AD$.

Let angle measures $\alpha, \alpha', \beta, \beta'$ be as indicated.

By the exterior angle theorem, $m\angle BDA = \alpha + \alpha'$ and 
$m\angle CDA = \beta + \beta'$.

Since $BD < AD$, then $\beta' < \beta$.

Since $CD < AD$, then $\alpha' < \alpha$.

Then
$2(\alpha' + \beta') < \alpha' + \beta' + \alpha + \beta = 180^\circ$.

Hence $m\angle BAC = \alpha' + \beta' < 90^\circ$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the origin of vectors and $\vec{AB} = \mathbf{b}$ and $\vec{AC} = \mathbf{c}$. Given $\left| \frac{\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c}}{2}\right| > \left| \frac{\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{c}}{2}\right| $ and hence $|\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{c}|^2 > |\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{c}|^2$ giving $\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{c} > 0$. Thus $\angle A$ is acute.